# warning popup when user try to move on other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to show the warning popup when user try to move on other page without saving the date.
i am using asp .net mvc 5 bootstroup menu.popup is coming but unable to stop loading other page while navigation to other page.

I need to navigate the user when they clicks Ok button if they click Cancel then they stays the same page.

```
 $(".dropdown-menu").on("click", "li", function() {
     var newMenu = $('a', this).attr('href');
     var confirm = bootbox.confirm({
         message: 'Rule is not saved, Do you want to save it?',
         buttons: {
             confirm: {
                 label: 'Continue without saving'
             },
             cancel: {
                 label: 'Save and Exit'
             }
         },
         callback: function(result) {
             if (result == true && is_dirty == false) {
                 window.location.href = newMenu;
             } else {
                 window.stop();
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: You can't prevent user to navigate away from your page.

Comment: @Teemu ; Thanks and I need to navigate the user when they clicks Ok button if they click Cancel then they stays the same page.

Comment: You can't, the user is the king here, they can go where ever they want with _their_  browser, no matter what you want. That what you want is simply not possible.

Comment: You can achieve this using a flag which is set true when the data is saved. Enable the button or link only if flag is set true

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve confirmation and achieve what you said using a flag which is set true when the data is saved. Enable the button or link only if flag is set true

```js
$('#btnfb').click(function(){
   var r = confirm("press ok to continue!");
    if (r == false) {
        return false;
    }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.faacebook.com" target="_blank" id="btnfb">Visit W3Schools!</a>
```